# Fresh Composer install is giving errors on a new git project cloned

Tags: php, composer-php

- I just cloned [this Git repo](https://github.com/laravue/laravue).
- Since this is a new computer, I installed a fresh copy of composer.
- Since this repo has its `composer.json` file, I ran `composer install`.
- Currently getting this error:

> Warning: require(G:\xampp\htdocs\laravue\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in G:\xampp\htdocs\laravue\bootstrap\autoload.php
>       on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'G:\xampp\htdocs\laravue\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='G:\xampp\php\PEAR') in G:\xampp\htdocs\laravue\bootst
>       rap\autoload.php on line 17
>       PHP Warning:  require(G:\xampp\htdocs\laravue\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in G:\xampp\htdocs\laravue\bootstrap\autoload
>       .php on line 17
>       PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'G:\xampp\htdocs\laravue\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='G:\xampp\php\PEAR') in G:\xampp\htdocs\laravue\b
>       ootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>       Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with error code 255

Since there is a fresh installation of this repo and there is no vendor dir yet, i'm **confused** as to why i'm getting this error.

Comment: Does this occur when you run `composer install` or when you're trying to access the site _after_ you ran composer install? If after, you should have a vendor folder.

Comment: this error occurs right after I type composer install, as noted in the question, there is no vendor folder yet as the composer install did not run.

Comment: Looking at the code, I'm confused as well. Even if the artisan commands (which is triggered after composer install in the composer.json) would fail, you should still get a vendor folder.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson and I thought this would be a walk in the park kind of composer error, any solution you could think of?

Comment: Found the issue. What happens is that the `pre-update-cmd` get's triggered, which uses php artisan which uses bootstrap/autoload.php. Here's from composers docs: _"pre-update-cmd: occurs before the update command is executed, **or before the install command is executed without a lock file present.**"_

Comment: This is something the developers need to address. I would create an issue.

Comment: This is a bug in laravue/laravue repository. It should indeed work out of the box. As @MagnusEriksson said, open an issue.

Comment: Open an issue with the maintainers and hope that after two years of no change in the repo, they still care.